# CakePHP redirect from plugin issue

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, redirect

I've made a CakePHP plugin. The code in PluginNameController extending PluginNameAppController is the following:

```
class PluginNameController extends PluginNameAppController {
    public function index() {
        $this->redirect(array('plugin' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action'=> 'login'));
    }
}
```

which should prompt users to log in, in order to make use of it,if they're not already logged in.
But this redirects to something like `example.com/plugin_name/users/login` and not at `example.com/users/login`, which is what I desire!
Can you help me out here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This syntax looks correct, weird that it doesn't work. What does `$this->redirect('/users/login');` do?

Comment: exactly the same, it redirects my to example.com/plugin_name/users/login :/

Comment: @koslibpro just confirm that you have used `parent::beforeFilter();` in beforefilter function.

Comment: yes, i confirm that i've used parent::beforeFilter() in beforeFilter  function

Comment: every thing looks fine...update your AppController, UsersController...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
public function index() {
        $this->redirect(array('plugin' => null, 'controller' => 'users', 'action'=> 'login'));
    }
```

Comment: What you have provided in $this->Auth->loginAction??

Comment: Set this:
$this->Auth->loginAction = array(‘controller’ => ‘users’, ‘action’ => ‘login’, ‘plugin’ => null); in your AppController inside beforeFilter function.

Comment: Now it returns a Error: Call to undefined method AuthComponent::loginAction(), thought i've included the Auth component..Does it have anything to do with it being a plugin?

Comment: I hope you have included this in your controller: public $components = array('Auth');

Comment: yes, of course i've included this but still it doesn't work :/

Comment: I fixed the error! Actually it didn't need to have Acl or Auth components included and then set the loginAction. The problem was that in the plugin's AppController, there were an issue which was causing the redirection inside the plugin only and i fixed it! Now with the code 'plugin' => null/false into the redirection snippet, everything works fine! Thank you guys!!